# How to compute volume of intersection of non-axis-aligned cuboids in 3D?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, volume

Given two cuboids in 3D space (8 vertex coordinates each) that are arbitrarily oriented, how can we find the volume of overlap between them in the fastest manner? An algorithm that one can code up would be great to know.

Comment: The intersection is a convex polyhedron, $P$ say. First find the vertices of $P$, then the faces. Triangulate each face. Choose an interior point, $O$ say, of $P$. For each triangle $ABC$ in the triangulation of the faces, compute the volume of tetrahedron $OABC$. The volume of $P$ is the sum of the volumes of those tetrahedra.

Comment: To implement from scratch the steps I outlined above would be a nontrivial task. Implementation using a CAS (e.g., Maple or Mathematica) would less painful, but still nontrivial. Alternatively, you could use a computational geometry package, which would make the program shorter, but the learning curve for using the package would itself be non-trivial. There's no free lunch on this one.

Comment: As a practical alternative, a Monte Carlo simulation can yield a fair approximation, and would not be too hard to implement.